# SciKit-Learn - Getting an Error when using OneHotEncoding within ColumnTransfer

Tags: python, pandas, scikit-learn

I'm getting the value error-TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['method', 'str']

I'm not sure why, as my features are object type.

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ohe=OneHotEncoder(sparse=False, handle_unknown='ignore')
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer

ct=ColumnTransformer([('ohe', ohe, updated_categorical_features)], remainder='passthrough')
z=ct.fit(df_train)
"TypeError: Encoders require their input to be uniformly strings or numbers. Got ['method', 'str'] "
```

However, when i check my dataframe for those features, they are only objects.

```
df_train[updated_categorical_features].info()

<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
RangeIndex: 1460 entries, 0 to 1459
Data columns (total 29 columns):
 #   Column         Non-Null Count  Dtype 
---  ------         --------------  ----- 
 0   MSZoning       1460 non-null   object
 1   Street         1460 non-null   object
 2   Alley          1460 non-null   object
 3   LotShape       1460 non-null   object
 4   LandContour    1460 non-null   object
 5   Utilities      1460 non-null   object
 6   LotConfig      1460 non-null   object
 7   LandSlope      1460 non-null   object
 8   Neighborhood   1460 non-null   object
 9   Condition1     1460 non-null   object
 10  Condition2     1460 non-null   object
 11  BldgType       1460 non-null   object
 12  HouseStyle     1460 non-null   object
 13  RoofStyle      1460 non-null   object
 14  RoofMatl       1460 non-null   object
 15  Exterior1st    1460 non-null   object
 16  Exterior2nd    1460 non-null   object
 17  MasVnrType     1460 non-null   object
 18  Foundation     1460 non-null   object
 19  Heating        1460 non-null   object
 20  CentralAir     1460 non-null   object
 21  Electrical     1460 non-null   object
 22  Functional     1460 non-null   object
 23  GarageType     1460 non-null   object
 24  PavedDrive     1460 non-null   object
 25  Fence          1460 non-null   object
 26  MiscFeature    1460 non-null   object
 27  SaleType       1460 non-null   object
 28  SaleCondition  1460 non-null   object
```

Any clarification would be great! Thanks.

Comment: `object` type is a catchall, so there could still be individual entries that are mixed strings and floats, e.g.  _But_, I don't know where `'method'` would be coming from...

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: What happens if you choose the default value 'remainder='drop' ? Also try not to ignore nan entries but prefer an imputer with some criterion. I have had your same problem yesterday and it was cause by something the like..